# SQL ORACLE - Datatable in where clause

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datatable

Currently I have a sql call returning a dataset from a MSSQL database and I want to take a column from that data and return ID's based off that column from the ORACLE database. I can do this one at a time but that requires multiple calls, I am wondering if this can be done with one call.

```
String sql=String.Format(@"Select DIST_NO
    FROM DISTRICT
    WHERE DIST_DESC = '{0}'", row.Table.Rows[0]["Op_Centre"].ToString());
```

Above is the string I am using to return one ID at a time. I know the {0} can be used to format your value into the string and maybe there is a way to do that with a datatable.

Also to use multiple values in the where clause it would be:

```
String sql=String.Format(@"Select DIST_NO
   FROM DISTRICT
   WHERE DIST_DESC in ('{0}')", row.Table.Rows[0] ["Op_Centre"].ToString());
```

Although I realize all of this can be done I am wondering if theres an easy way to add it all to the sql string in one call.

As I am writing this I am realizing I could break the string into sections then just add every row value to the SQL string within the "WHERE DIST_DESC IN (" clause...

I am still curious to see if there is another way though, and because someone else may come across this problem I will post a solution if I develop one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not what you're asking, which is why this is a comment, but:

Don't suppose your MSSQL database can be set up to see the Oracle database, can it? You can use Oracle/ODBC drivers on SQL Server to add an Oracle database as a linked server and JOIN to it directly using linked server or OpenQuery syntax. Then you could write your query entirely in MSSQL and call it on the SQL Server, and the SQL Server would deal with talking to Oracle and dragging the data back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most RDBMS-agnostic approach you could do is to create a temporary table.  Then just query: `select * from district where dist_desc in (select dist_desc from temp_table)`

There's a solution here in Oracle http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=930372 , but I don't have Oracle in my box, so I can't try how it will work in .NET.

Have tried this in Postgresql http://fxjr.blogspot.com/2009/05/npgsql-tips-using-in-queries-with.html , have very seamless support for comparing value to list

If you will go the dynamic query approach, try this:

```
String sql=String.Format(@"Select DIST_NO
FROM DISTRICT
WHERE DIST_DESC IN ({0})", 
  string.Join( ",",
      ds.Tables[0].Select()
      .Select(r => "'" + (string)r["Op_Centre"] + "'").ToArray() ) // string.Join
  ); // string.Format
```

Answer (score 1):

K I understand its pointless to ask a question and then answer it yourself but by asking the question I realized the answer.

String sql = "Select DIST_NO FROM DISTRICT WHERE DIST_DESC in ('" +ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Op_Centre"].ToString()+"'";

for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++ )

{
sql +=",'"+ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Op_Centre"].ToString()+"'";

}
sql += ")";

I am still curious to see if there is a better way though...